# How to use items?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

How to use meds or burn books to heat up the house ?

I cannot find how to use the items in my inventory, when opening the inventory everything is grayed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use an itens when the game "enable" its use for you

You can use Meds when a character is ill,
http://thiswarofmine.gamepedia.com/Medications

And the books, its good to keep some of them, but to burn it you should convert it to fuel in the workshop.
http://this-war-of-mine.wikia.com/wiki/Book

There are these wiki with tips and survival guides
http://this-war-of-mine.wikia.com/wiki/Items
http://thiswarofmine.gamepedia.com/

Comment: Do you know if cigarettes gets used automatically ?

Comment: Yes, In Our Things, you can see the smoke per day.
The animation effect don't consume any coffee or cigarette. If you set the char idle for some seconds it will start one.
They always consume the one you have most(i don't know if its in the game code, but some players related that and I seems true so far), so try to make more herbal, so you don't lose the tobacco ones.